# Element taken out of the normal document flow

Tags: html, css

An element that is positioned with absolute positioning is taken out of the normal document flow hence will not effect other elements within the same document.

If we now look at an element that is being floated it also seems that it is taken out of the normal document flow but it still affects other elements. Is it correct to say that an element that is floated is taken out of the normal document flow?

Comment: You don't use flow and absolute positioning together. The statement is not correct. You always have to decide what is best, but if you have elements that flow relatively to other elements, avoid using position absolute.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Normal flow, floats and absolute positioning are all [distinct layout methods](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#comparison).

Comment: I was told to to accept some answers from my previous questions in order for the community to help you. Community helps you, you should give back too. How do I do that ?

Comment: @user2658578, select the tick next to an answer. I would suggest reading the [about] page. You also gain a badge for doing this!